# i build url parameter using http_buid_query, how do i convert it back to array

Tags: php, arrays, json

i have an array like this

```php
$approve =["approval" => 1,"record" => $recordId,"employee" => $userid];
```

which i used to build URL parameter with, using the

```php
$approve = http_build_query($approve)
```

now i want to convert that back to array/JSON. I tried using

```php
json_encode(explode('&',$approve));
```

and this is the result i get

```
[
    "approval=1",
    "record=8",
    "employee=2",
    "hod=9"
]
```

Comment: why override ```$approve``` variable?, just assign different variable on your ```http_build_query``` so you can still access the original array

Comment: Most PHP manual pages have a handy section titled [See Also](https://www.php.net/manual/function.http-build-query.php#refsect1-function.http-build-query-seealso) which details related functions. You want [parse_str()](https://www.php.net/manual/function.parse-str.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```php
parse_str($approve, $array);
```

And the `$array` variable will hold your parsed query string.

Comment: @wlliam Evans thanks its working